# Rearranging vectors into matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have data and it is arranged in following order

[image: test_data]

Now you can see for every `x` value there are different `y` values and respectively some real and img values. `x` has a dimension `m x 1` and `y` has a dimension `n x 1`.  Now I want to arrange data in a new matrix in such a way that new matrix has a dimension of `m x n`. In other words the `x` will be my row and values of `y` will be my columns and correspondingly for each `x` and `y` the value comes into the new matrix as follows.

```
new_matrix(m,n)= real*exp{img}
```

i.e. For each `x` and `y` values the real part should multiply with exponential of imaginary part and comes into the new matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB uses column-major indexing so if you create a matrix that is `m` x `n` and then fill it, it will fill down the rows first and then across the columns. Your is ordered in row-major order (and if it's not we can use `sortrows` to ensure that it is). We can then just compute the `real * exp(imag)` using the last two columns and reshape it to be `n` x `m` and then transpose it to get your `m` x `n` matrix.

```
data = [0   1   25  12
        0   2   15  26
        1   1   78  26
        1   2   25  63
        2   1   26  35
        2   2   45  63
        3   1   56  26
        3   2   48  2];

% Ensure that the data is in the correct order
data = sortrows(data);

% Determine the size of the output matrix
m = numel(unique(data(:,1)));
n = numel(unique(data(:,2)));

% Compute real * exp(imag) and make it the correct shape
out = reshape(data(:,3) .* exp(data(:,4)), n, m).';

%   4.0689e+06   2.9359e+12
%   1.5267e+13   5.7345e+28
%   4.1236e+16   1.0322e+29
%   1.0961e+13   3.5467e+02
```

Answer (score 1):

What you got is a sparse representation of a matrix. Using the sparse constructior is the simplest (but maybe not the fastest) way to get your matrix:

```
full(sparse(data(:,1)+1,data(:,2),data(:,3) .* exp(data(:,4))))
```